# VBScript implicit conversion in IF statement different from variable to literals?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, literals

We are currently having an issue due to implicit conversion in an IF statement in VBScript (Classic ASP) that don't do implicit conversion the same way when dealing with a variable or a literal. Can someone explain this behavior to me, why do VBScript acts this way ?

Here is a sample of what I mean :

```
Const c_test = 3
Dim iId : iId = 3
Dim iTestStr : iTestStr = "3"

If iId = iTestStr Then
    Response.Write("Long variable = String variable : Equal")
Else
    Response.Write("Long variable = String variable : Not Equal")
End If

Response.Write("<br/>")

If c_test = iTestStr Then
    Response.Write("Long constant = String variable : Equal")
Else
    Response.Write("Long constant = String variable : Not Equal")
End If

Response.Write("<br/>")

If c_test = iId Then
    Response.Write("Long constant = Long variable : Equal")
Else
    Response.Write("Long constant = Long variable : Not Equal")
End If

Response.Write("<br/>")

If iId = "3" Then
    Response.Write("Long variable = String literal : Equal")
Else
    Response.Write("Long variable = String literal : Not Equal")
End If

Response.Write("<br/>")

If c_test = "3" Then
    Response.Write("Long constant = String literal : Equal")
Else
    Response.Write("Long constant = String literal : Not Equal")
End If
```

Which ouputs :

Long variable = String variable : Not Equal

Long constant = String variable : Not Equal

Long constant = Long variable : Equal

Long variable = String literal : Equal

Long constant = String literal : Equal

Which is quite confusing o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are (implicitly) declaring your variables `As Variant` so your `If` conditions actually test the equality of two `Variant`s and determine that they are unequal.

In the last cases, however, you are using `String` constants (which can never be `Variant`, even if declared without a type) and `String` literals.

My *guess* is that when you compare two `Variant`s, VB first determines whether they have the same type tag and if they don’t, resolves to `False`.

Comment: I tested the types of variables and constants with VBScript function "VarType", and none of them is Variant, it turns out that they are vbInteger (for the iId and c_test) and vbString for iTestStr. By the way, VBScript does not allow variable type declaration.

Comment: @Maxi: I had forgotten that. But the variables are *still* of type `Variant`, and `VarType` actually *extracts* the type tag from a `Variant`, which is why you get another result. `VarType` may also return `vbVariant`, but this is only the case for *arrays* of `Variant`s.

Comment: I will accept your solution which seems logic, even if I have no way to confirm it's absolutely right ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This is the result of one documented behavior and one undocumented one.

---

The documented behavior is that in comparisons, a number is always less than a string. This is mentioned in the documentation for [Comparison Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Paraphrasing the table near the bottom of the page:

> **If** one expression is numeric and the other is a string, **then** the numeric expression is less than the string expression.

---

The undocumented behavior is that comparisons involving literals are handled differently from comparisons involving variables. See [this blog entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/typing-hard-can-trip-you-up) for more details. To summarize the important conclusion:

> The relevant comparison rules in VB6/VBScript go like this:
>
> - Hard string ~ hard number: convert string to number, compare numbers
> - Hard string ~ soft number: convert number to string, compare strings
> - Soft string ~ hard number: convert string to number, compare numbers
> - Soft string ~ soft number: any string is greater than any number

---

The documented behavior explains why the first two comparisons are false, while the undocumented behavior explains why the last two comparisons are true.