# Integer and String comparison conflict in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

The below VBScript code while trying to run in HP-UFT confused me because the first statement prints `True` instead of `False` (which does not seem logical), while the second one prints `False` (which seems logical)

Code:

```
print 40 = "40"

a = 40
b = "40"
print a = b
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Isn't VBScript amazing? Things equal to the same are not equal to each other; comparing variables is different than comparing the values in them. Think of all the work that we had to do to make these completely crazy semantics!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's perfectly logical (*cough*), there is only one data type in VBScript and that is `Variant`. However VBScript can handle many different sub types of the `Variant` data type.

When you compare

```
40 = "40"
```

VBScript is implicitly converting the `String` sub type to an `Integer` sub type and comparing the result which is the same as performing the following explicit conversion;

```
40 = CInt("40")
```

If you already have your variants defined however VBScript only attempts to implicitly convert them if the execution context fits *(when it fits is a bit hazy and in some cases a straight up bug - See [Ref](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/07/30/typing-hard-can-trip-you-up/))*.

To avoid this use explicit conversions when necessary.

```
a = CInt(b)
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [A: VBScript implicit conversion in IF statement different from variable to literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13785257/692942)
- [MSDN Blog - Typing Hard Can Trip You Up (Eric Lippert)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/07/30/typing-hard-can-trip-you-up/)

Comment: @Shubham Kundu - Just to add to what @Lankysmart said - You can also use `VarType` function to check the variable's type just in case you want to be sure. QTP's help is great for VarType. Read it once.

Comment: @PankajJaju There's also `TypeName()` which gives you a friendlier output.

Comment: Yes. It returns a string which I personally don't like for conditional checking.

Comment: @Lankysmart - Sidenote --- Thanks for Eric's excellent article.