# How can "1" be greater than 50?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, type-conversion

I'm baffled by the following and hope I'm about to learn something.
When I run the following code:

```
<%
Response.Write "ss = ""1""<br/>"
ss = "1"
Response.Write "ii = 50<br/>"
ii = 50
Response.Write "ss >= ii "
If ss >= ii Then Response.Write "True?" Else Response.Write "False"
Response.Write "<br/>""1"" >= 50 "
If "1" >= 50 Then Response.Write "True" Else Response.Write "False"
%>
```

It writes:

```
ss = "1"
ii = 50
ss >= ii True?
"1" >= 50 False
```

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t.aspx) 
If operands are One numeric and one String Comparison is The String is converted to a Double and numeric comparison is performed. If the String cannot be converted to Double, an InvalidCastException is thrown.

I'm using ASP version 5.8, build number 18525.

I don't require a workaround as I have one but I was wondering if there is a reason for this as it's an easy mistake to make.

Edit: Chosen correct answer has a comment with a further link to detail of the difference between the 2 comparisons.

Comment: Actually the `Version 5.8` likely refers to VBScript version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer and String comparison conflict in VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465831/integer-and-string-comparison-conflict-in-vbscript)

Comment: use `if CLng(x) > CLng(y) then`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at documentation for .NET, while using VBScript (which is not a .NET language). To quote the VBScript language reference, then when comparing a string to a number,

> The numeric expression is less than the string expression.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.85).aspx)

The reason your second `if` evaluates to `False` is because of [the way VBScript treats variables and literals differently in comparisons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/07/30/typing-hard-can-trip-you-up/). Because you have a literal number, the literal string *is* being converted as you initially expected.

Comment: Ah yes thanks. That explains the first comparison and means that it is correct but I think makes the second one wrong?

Comment: @Banzivar That's because literals are apparently treated differently, for reasons of backwards-compatibility with VB6. [Eric Lippert has a blog post with some detail](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/07/30/typing-hard-can-trip-you-up/).

Comment: Apparently it's just a bug that wasn't important enough to fix at the time. - Already covered here [A: Integer and String comparison conflict in VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40466467/692942).