# Syntax error in Classic ASP file with server-side-include

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have an `if` statement containing a `<table>` with two rows, like so:

```
<%
    ...
    If Not Request("InsertPlacement") <> "" Then
%>

<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- #include file="UserHeader.asp" -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<% End If %>
```

Now I have a whole bunch of compile errors saying things like "if must end with matching end if" (which it does) and "statement cannot appear outside of a method body" (huh? it's in a `<%%>` tag) and "declaration expected" (makes no sense at all).

If I delete both of the `<tr>` tags inside the `<table>`, or delete the whole `<table>`, the compile errors go away. *However* - if I delete one or the other `<tr>` tag, doesn't matter which, the errors do *not* go away. So which `<tr>` tag is causing the error? It's like the dual slit experiment - the error comes through either `<tr>` tag regardless of which I delete! What the heck could be going on here?!

Comment: It’s called a Heisenbug: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug - whereas a “quantum” bug would be irreducible.

Comment: This is Classic ASP code, not ASP.NET. Please correct the title and tags of this question.

Comment: @Dai It's both. The page itself is ASP.NET, but the include file is classic ASP. (Apparently you can actually do that?)

Comment: no, you can’t. That’s probably part of the problem. Also, your `If` statement has a double-negative.

Comment: Your HTML table markup won’t be involved even if this page is being run through ASP.NET or Classic ASP because neither attempt to parse HTML - they treat all runs of HTML as a giant string literal (except when ASP.NET encounters `runat=“server”`- or if you’re using Razor.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think that was the problem, because if I delete the first row, containing the include statement, the errors persist. As for the double negative, I would "fix" that but I'm hesitant to break some weird edge case since VB does all sorts of automatic type casting in the background...

Comment: I think you should post the entire file rather than just a fragment of it - please post both the file in-question *and* the `UserHeader.asp` file.

Comment: `... since VB does all sorts of automatic type casting in the background`. One example?

Comment: _since VB does all sorts of automatic type casting in the background_ is called LET Coercion. EG `msgbox 1 + 2` will print a string containing the character 3. The rules are specified in implementation detail here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx and contractually in the help. The actual functions are in OLEAUT32.DLL. `Msgbox 2 / 1.5` will start with 2 as an integer, then it will be converted to a double, and devided by a double of 1.5.  You could use strings instead of integers and doubles and the strings will be converted to doubles.

Comment: @Mark Classic ASP uses VBScript, not VB, VBA etc. Yes they are very similar but VBScript unlike it's cousins is Typeless, all data types are a subtype of `Variant`.

Comment: I also can't think of a single language that doesn't auto coerce numbers to strings when you print them.

Comment: And each of those variants need to be coerced as well. A variant is not typeless (vbscript is) but contains the type. ` A = 3` and `A = "3"` the first gives you a variant with a type of integer (let coercion rules) the second as a string as vartype shows.

Comment: @Mark don't need a lesson in coerce, was referring more to this specifically related to VBScript - See [Integer and String comparison conflict in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40466467/692942)

Comment: If you want the include to be self-contained, you can run `Server.Execute("UserHeader.asp")` instead of using an `include` statement. Then there should be no risk of cross contamination. However, depending on your setup this may not be feasible. Despite being within an if-statement, the include will load, whether or not the if statement is true.

Answer (score 2):

Your `UserHeader.asp` file will contain a mismatched or broken control-flow statement.

Server-side-includes are evaluated before the VBScript interpreter runs.

(Compared with PHP where require/include are evaluated when executed)

Comment: That can't be the problem, because if I delete the table row containing that include statement, the errors don't go away.

Comment: Oh wait, I spoke too soon - if I delete the table row containing the include statement, *then* close and reopen the file, I get some more reasonable looking errors!

Comment: I bet, if you remove the `If` block in your page but leave the include in tact it will work. Likelihood is you have a `Function` or `Sub` defined inside the include file which can't exist inside a control-flow statement like an `If`. Which makes the error pretty self explanatory.

Comment: @Lankymart What amazes me the most is that someone is actually doing a Classic ASP project in 2020 - that's almost 18 years since it was officially replaced with ASP.NET WebForms (not that WebForms was an improvement either...)

Comment: @Dai can't say I'm a fan of WebForms but Classic ASP will always hold a special place in my heart. It's very easy to do wrong but also very robust when done right. Moved on to ASP.Net MVC now though and skipped WebForms altogether.

Comment: @Lankymart You missed out on a lot :D https://stackoverflow.com/a/51391202/159145