# VBS numerical const not working in >= comparison for loop

Tags: vbscript

I've run into a weird issue (IMHO) which may just be highlighting my ignorance when it comes to VBS vs. other programming languages. Here's what I have at the top of my .VBS file.

```
Option Explicit
Const MAXROWSFOREXCEL2010 = 1048576
```

I then have the following conditional check in a loop:

```
If numLines >= MAXROWSFOREXCEL2010 Then
   wscript.echo "Inside the numLines If Then Statement"
   wscript.echo "numLines = " & numLines & " >= " & MAXROWSFOREXCEL2010
```

As an example, let's say numLines is equal to 107563, which is clearly less than the 1 million plus value assigned to MAXROWSFOREXCEL2010 as a global const above.

For whatever reason, the IF statement is being executed, even when numLines is clearly less than the const.

However, if I remove the use of the const in the comparison, and just put the hard coded value of MAXROWSFOREXCEL2010 into the loop such as:

```
If numLines >= 1048576 Then
   wscript.echo "Inside the numLines If Then Statement"
   wscript.echo "numLines = " & numLines & " >= " & MAXROWSFOREXCEL2010
```

Then the IF statement is NOT entered incorrectly.

Can someone clue me in to why this is the case? Should I be somehow declaring the const as a particular data type? Is there some sort of truncation of the const going on?

Comment: @JNevill Why did this get an up-vote? VBScript is typeless everything is a `Variant` or sub-type of it. Seriously, how many people don't know the difference between VBScript, VBA and VB? - *wishes you could down-vote comments...*

Comment: @Lankymart Pardon. I misread the question. I will remove the comment. You may want to delete or rewrite your obnoxious rhetorical questions as well. It still feels like perhaps OP is running into a lexicographical sort though.

Comment: @JNevill no problem, to be honest, my *"rhetorical questions"* were aimed more at the fact that it got up-voted. One person misreading a question is fine *(I guess)* but two.

Comment: @SliderJeff, going out on a limb here based on the Lexicographical sort assumption (which is a big fat assumption), perhaps try `If numLines >= (0+MAXROWSFOREXCEL2010)` to see if that forces variant to act as numeric in this context.

Comment: @JNevill it's certainly worth a try.

Comment: @SliderJeff is the `numLines` definitely a numeric data type if you check it with `result = VarType(numLines)`? Reason I ask is this might be relevant - [VBScript implicit conversion in IF statement different from variable to literals?](//stackoverflow.com/a/13785257).

Comment: @JNevil Unfortunately, trying to force the variant to act as numeric didn't seem to change the behavior.  Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: @Lankymart That might be the issue since I am not explicitly defining numLines type as numerical in nature.  I will do so and let you know what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it appears that my numLines is being seen as a string, hence the result value equaling 8 when I perform the 'result = VarType(numLines)? '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be [inclined to suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049258/vbs-numerical-const-not-working-in-comparison-for-loop/43051458#comment73184597_43049258) the problem is `numLines` not being numeric rather than there being a problem with the `Const` value, in which case this question answers the problem.

> <sup>From [A:VBScript implicit conversion in IF statement different from variable to literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13785257/692942) by [@cheran-shunmugavel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249624/cheran-shunmugavel)</sup>
>   *The documented behavior is that in comparisons, a number is always less than a string. This is mentioned in the documentation for [Comparison Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Paraphrasing the table near the bottom of the page:*
>
> ***If*** one expression is numeric and the other is a string, **then** the numeric expression is less than the string expression.

With that in mind you simply need to make sure the variable `numLines` is explicitly a numeric value using an explicit cast.

```
'Explicitly cast variable to Long
numLines = CLng(numLines)
```

Comment: Thanks!  As I stated below, I did that very thing before returning the return value of the function that actually counts and returns the number of lines into numLines.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I believe what's going on is a quirk of the way VBS attempts to determine data types. I also believe you're `numLines` variable is being evaluated as a `String`.

You can do `Wscript.Echo TypeName(numLines)` to verify this. I can replicate your issue when I set `numLines` equal to `"107563"` instead of `107563`.

If a value is "boxed" in VBS, in the case of your const `MAXROWSFOREXCEL2010`, the engine will attempt to perform the comparison operation differently than if it's not. In this case, because `numLines` is a string *and* the comparison is against a boxed variable, it attempts to do a (bitwise) string comparison. If `numLines` is a string and the comparison is against an explicit `Integer` the comparison is done as a (bitwise) integer comparison.

If `numLines` was an `Integer` this problem doesn't happen.

Here are some more examples:

```
strOne = "1"
intOne = 1
If "1" = 1 Then WScript.Echo "true" Else WScript.Echo "false"
If "1" = intOne Then WScript.Echo "true" Else wscript.Echo "false"
If strOne = 1 Then WScript.Echo "true" Else wscript.Echo "false"
If strOne = intOne Then WScript.Echo "true" Else wscript.Echo "false"
```

Output

```
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: Yeah, like [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049258/vbs-numerical-const-not-working-in-comparison-for-loop#comment73184597_43049258), in which case it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Langstrom  Sorry, can you explain the "boxed" comment?  Is there a way I can force numLines to be seen as a LONG, as well as the const to be seen that way, such that the comparison will be a truly arithmetic compare?  Sorry for my ignorance on this stuff.

Comment: Perhaps I need to perform CLng(numLines)?

Comment: @SliderJeff that is exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: Yep, that worked.  For reference, numLines was actually a returned value from a Function which counted the number of lines in a CSV file.  I simply used the CLng(numLines) conversion as the last step before returning the value of the Function and now the comparison is all good.  Thanks for your help, gang!